# Facebook Login Button work but doesn't sign in successfully

Tags: java, android, facebook, firebase

I am using facebook login in my app when I press the button it works as normal after I press On continue as (UserName) nothing happens at all the app is connected to firebase I have added two toasts to check if the signing in process failed or not but none of them appear at all neither the toast that should appear when it failed nor the other toast that should appear when it works

this is my activity code :

```
public class GeneralSignActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    SignInButton button;
    private final static int RC_SIGN_IN = 2;
    private final String TAG = "Logging";
    CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_general_sign);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        button = findViewById(R.id.googleBtn);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

       gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(GeneralSignActivity.this, "حدث خطأ برجاء اعادة المحاولة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn();
            }
        });

        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = findViewById(R.id.facebookBtn);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                Toast.makeText(GeneralSignActivity.this, "نجح تسجيل الدخول", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
                // ...
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Intent i = new Intent(GeneralSignActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            Toast.makeText(GeneralSignActivity.this, "handle facebook access token.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(GeneralSignActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           // updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btnSignUp)
    void click(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btnSignIn)
    void click2(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
                Toast.makeText(this, "نجح تسجيل الدخول",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(GeneralSignActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Toast.makeText(GeneralSignActivity.this, "حدث خطأ أثناء محاولة التسجيل برجاء اعادة المحاولة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }//TODO
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            //updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(GeneralSignActivity.this, "Authentication Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(GeneralSignActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not using Toasts in `onCancel()` or `onError()`. Were you expecting Toasts, or was that just a typo in your question? You should be checking your logcat for those.

Comment: I will check them

Comment: Have you enabled facebook authentication in your Firebase Console? Please responde with @.